# Which monster attacks are affected by guard up?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I'm a big fan of guard lancing. An armor skill that is often suggested for this style of play is guard up. The description of guard up says it causes previously unblockable attacks to become blockable.

**I'm looking for a list of monsters that this skill is relevant against (along with the moves which are affected).** This way I can gem in the skill for relevant fights and switch to something else when hunting monsters it is useless against.

It would also be good to know if there are any attacks that the skill does not allow you to block. In my search I found doubts if Teostra nova or Dalamadur super lazer could be blocked.

Comment: most monsters that have a "death laser" are usually what you need guard-up for. I don't have a full list on hand, but that's basically how it is.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've been able to gather through experience and various places on the internet, the only thing you definitely can't block with Guard Up is Dalamadur's beam attack.

I'm unsure about Teostra's supernova, Fatalis' explosions, or Gogmazios' massive tar explosions, but I think it's likely that you'd be able to block them albeit with massive knockback.